How use each in cypress when element is detached from DOM after action
I have this cypress code and it works. I need to iterate through all the links on the page. After clicking on each link, a breadcrumb tab opens. After closing the tab, the page with the links returns.
cy.get('a').then(($el) => {
            const aCount = $el.length
            for (let i = 0; i < aCount; i++) {
                cy.get('a').eq(i).click();
                cy.get('.close-btn').click() 
                cy.get('a').should('be.visible')
            }
        })

But I am trying to rewrite it with each method keep getting the same error.

...failed because the page updated as a result of this command, but you tried to continue the command chain...

With each I tried many variations, eg. this and the error remains. Can you provide any hint, why is this happening and how to make each method works?
cy.get('a').each(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).click();
    cy.get('.close-btn').click();
})

I tried use eg. then I would expect same behaviour as for loop.
cy.get('a').each(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).should('be.visible').then(() => {
        cy.wrap($el).click().then(() => {
            cy.get('.close-button').click();

